# Return Row with schema defined at runtime in Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, databricks, user-defined-functions

I've dulled my sword on this one, some help would be greatly appreciated!

## Background

I am building an ETL pipeline that takes GNMI Protobuf update messages off of a Kafka queue and eventually breaks them out into a bunch of delta tables based on the prefix and parameters of the paths to values (e.g. DataBricks runtime).

Without going into the gory details, each prefix corresponds roughly to a schema for a table, with the caveat that the paths can change (usually new subtrees) upstream, so the schema is not fixed.  This is similar to a nested JSON structure .

I first break out the updates by prefix, so all of the updates have roughly the same schema.  I defined some transformations so that when the schema does not match exactly, I can coerce them into a common schema.

I'm running into trouble when I try to create a struct column with the common schema.

## Attempt 1

I first tried just returning an `Array[Any]` from my udf, and providing a schema in the UDF definition (I know this is deprecated):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F, Row, types => T}

  def mapToRow(deserialized: Map[String, ParsedValueV2]): Array[Any] = {
    def getValue(key: String): Any = {
        deserialized.get(key) match {
            case Some(value) => value.asType(columns(key))
            case None => None
        }
    }
    
    columns.keys.toArray.map(getValue).toArray
  }
  
  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF", "true")
  def mapToStructUdf = F.udf(mapToRow _, account.sparkSchemas(prefix))
```

This snippet creates an `Array` object with the typed values that I need. Unfortunately when I try to use the UDF, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to $line8760b7c10da04d2489451bb90ca42c6535.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$ParsedValueV2
```

I'm not sure what's not matching, but I did notice that the type of the values are Java types, not scala, so perhaps that is related?

## Attempt 2

Maybe I can use the Typed UDF interface after all?  Can I create a case class at runtime for each schema, and then use that as the return value from my udf?

I've tried to get this to work using various stuff I found like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
val test = tb.eval(tb.parse("object Test; Test"))
```

but I can't even get an instance of `test`, and can't figure out how to use it as the return value of a UDF.  I presume I need to use a generic type somehow, but my scala-fu is too weak to figure this one out.

## Finally, the question

Can some help me figure out which approach to take, and how to proceed with that approach?

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

## Update - is this a Spark bug?

I've distilled the problem down to this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F, Row, types => T}

// thanks @Dmytro Mitin
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master ("local")
  .appName ("Spark app")
  .getOrCreate ()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF", "true")

def simpleFn(foo: Any): Seq[Any] = List("hello world", "Another String", 42L)
// def simpleFn(foo: Any): Seq[Any] = List("hello world", "Another String")

def simpleUdf = F.udf(
  simpleFn(_),
  dataType = T.StructType(
    List(
      T.StructField("a_string", T.StringType),
      T.StructField("another_string", T.StringType),
      T.StructField("an_int", T.IntegerType),
    )
  )
)

Seq(("bar", "foo"))
  .toDF("column", "input")
  .withColumn(
    "array_data",
    simpleUdf($"input")
  )
  .show(truncate=false)
```

which results in this error message

```
IllegalArgumentException: The value (List(Another String, 42)) of the type (scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon) cannot be converted to the string type
```

Hmm... that's odd. Where does that list come from, missing the first element of the row?

Two valued version (e.g. "hello world", "Another String") has the same problem, but if I only have one value in my struct, then its happy:

```
// def simpleFn(foo: Any): Seq[Any] = List("hello world", "Another String")
def simpleFn(foo: Any): Seq[Any] = List("hello world")

def simpleUdf = F.udf(
  simpleFn(_),
  dataType = T.StructType(
    List(
      T.StructField("a_string", T.StringType),
      // T.StructField("another_string", T.StringType),
      // T.StructField("an_int", T.IntegerType),
    )
  )
)
```

and my query gives me

```
+------+-----+-------------+
|column|input|array_data   |
+------+-----+-------------+
|bar   |foo  |{hello world}|
+------+-----+-------------+
```

It looks like its giving me the first element of my Sequence as the first field of the struct, the rest of it as the second element of the struct, and then the third one is null (seen in other cases), and causes an exception.

This looks like a bug to me.  Anyone else have any experience with UDFs with schemas built on the fly like this?

Spark 3.3.1, scala 2.12, DBR 12.0

## Reflection struggles

A stupid way to accomplish what I want to do would be to take the schema's I've inferred, generate a bunch of scala code that implements case classes that I can use as return types from my UDFs, then compile the code, package up a JAR, load it into my databricks runtime, and then use the case classes as return results from the UDFs.

This seems like a very convoluted way to do things.  It would be great if I could just generate the case classes, and then do something like

```
  def myUdf[CaseClass](input: SomeInputType): CaseClass = 
    CaseClass(input.giveMeResults: _*)
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the type I've created using eval into the current "context" (I don't know the right word here).

This code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
val test = tb.eval(tb.parse("object Test; Test"))
```

give me this:

```
...
test: Any = __wrapper$1$bb89c0cde37c48929fa9d8cdabeeb0f8.__wrapper$1$bb89c0cde37c48929fa9d8cdabeeb0f8$Test$1$@492531c0
```

test is, I think, an instance of Test, but the type system in the REPL doesn't know about any type named Test, so I can't use `test.asInstanceOf[Test]` or something like that

I know this is a frequently asked question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere about how to actually accomplish what I described above.

Comment: None of your code snippets is self-contained. They do not compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UXXRqywsSd2o3WLbIojh8Q https://scastie.scala-lang.org/V5OpfppjSgOkpCz5WmUFHg Do you have [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Regarding runtime-generated class/object (Attempt 2) I'm not sure I understand what you consider to be wrong. *"I can't even get an instance of `Test`"* The value of variable `test` is exactly the instance of object `Test` https://scastie.scala-lang.org/noC565vQS7e6kQXIixlc1w Or if `Test` is a case class rather than object then the code should be https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pIPTRgi3Qsy6hj4G2EW5gg or https://scastie.scala-lang.org/myG3dVulQaKoSvBU29feOA Let `Test` be ordinary compile-time case class or object. What code would you write? We can try to adopt it for the runtime-generated case.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, that's what the `simpleFn` snippets were meant to be.  I think you only need to add import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F, Row, types => T} and the spark builder like you did to make them work. Right now I working from a DataBricks notebook, so I missed that they don't compile out of context.

Comment: Regarding runtime-generated case classes, what I get back from the eval is not usable as declared type.  I need this in order to use it as the return result of a UDF.  The result from the eval is of type Any, and I can't find any way to import the actual type into the REPL.  I'm clearly misunderstanding here.  I'll add some more detail to my question

Comment: Thanks. Now in `simpleFn` snippet I have `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: You're using untyped Scala UDF, which does not have the input type information ... To get rid of this error, you could ...` https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/bb961610789f60abb550d6675b00ce15 How should I fix this in order to reproduce?

Comment: *"what I get back from the `eval` is not usable as declared type"* `eval` returns an **instance**. Not sure I understand how you would use it as declared **type** even for ordinary case class/object. If you mean the **type** of generated class/object then yes you can use it further, just if you started to work with toolbox you'll have to continue with toolbox or reflection. For example if you have `def foo[T] = ???` then you'll have to call it like `tb.eval(q"foo[testSymbol]")`. See my Scastie snippet with `tb.define`.

Comment: Here is the magic you need to get past that error:   spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF", "true")

I added it above too.

Comment: Regarding what I'm trying to do, I would like to use the generated class as a type parameter for `myUdf` above.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. With the magic I managed to reproduce. Regarding "Reflection struggles". Do you already have `def myUdf[T] = ...` from somewhere and you're trying just to call it for generated case class `foo[GeneratedClass]` (pseudocode) or are you trying to define `def myUdf[T] = ...` based on the generated class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251609/discussion-between-user961826-and-dmytro-mitin).

Comment: Please see the answer. Feel free to ask for further clarifications.

Comment: See the update regarding `ClassCastException` or `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "Reflection struggles". It's not clear for me whether: 1) you already have `def myUdf[T] = ...` from somewhere and you're trying just to call it for generated case class: `myUdf[GeneratedClass]` or 2) you're trying to define `def myUdf[T] = ...` based on the generated class.

1. In the former case you should use:

- `tb.define` to generate an object (or case class), it returns a class symbol (or module symbol), you can use it further (e.g. in a type position)
- `tb.eval` to call the method (`myUdf`)

```
object Main extends App {
  def myUdf[T](): Unit = println("myUdf")

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  import universe.Quasiquote
  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

  val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
  val testSymbol = tb.define(q"object Test")
  val test = tb.eval(q"$testSymbol")

  tb.eval(q"Main.myUdf[$testSymbol]()") // myUdf
}
```

In this example I changed the signature (and body) of `myUdf`, you should use your actual ones.

2. In the latter case you can define `myUdf` at runtime too:

```
object Main extends App {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  import universe.Quasiquote
  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

  val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
  val testSymbol = tb.define(q"object Test")
  val test = tb.eval(q"$testSymbol")

  val xSymbol = tb.define(
    q"""
      object X {
        def myUdf[T](): Unit = println("myUdf")
      }
    """
  )

  tb.eval(q"$xSymbol.myUdf[$testSymbol]()") //myUdf
}
```

You should try to write `myUdf` for ordinary case and we'll translate it for runtime-generated one.

> so I can't use `test.asInstanceOf[Test]` or something like that

Yeah, type `Test` doesn't exist at compile time so you can't use it like that. It exists at runtime so you should use it inside quasiquotes `q"..."` (or `tb.parse("...")`)

```
object Main extends App {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  import universe.Quasiquote
  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

  val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
  val testSymbol = tb.define(q"object Test")
  val test = tb.eval(q"$testSymbol")

  tb.eval(q"Main.test.asInstanceOf[${testSymbol.asModule.moduleClass.asClass.toType}]") // no exception, so test is an instance of Test
  tb.eval(q"Main.test.asInstanceOf[$testSymbol.type]") // no exception, so test is an instance of Test
  println(
    tb.eval(q"Main.test.getClass").asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
  ) // class __wrapper$1$0bbb246b633b472e8df54efc3e9ff9d9.Test$
  println(
    tb.eval(q"scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[$testSymbol.type]").asInstanceOf[universe.Type]
  ) // __wrapper$1$0bbb246b633b472e8df54efc3e9ff9d9.Test.type
}
```

---

Regarding `ClassCastException` or `IllegalArgumentException`. I noticed that the exception disappears if you change UDF return type

```
def simpleUdf = F.udf (
  simpleFn (_),
  dataType = T.StructType (
    List (
      T.StructField ("a_string", T.StringType),
      T.StructField ("tail1", T.StructType (
        List (
          T.StructField ("another_string", T.StringType),
          T.StructField ("tail2", T.StructType (
            List (
              T.StructField ("an_int", T.IntegerType),
            )
          )),
        )
      )),
    )
  )
)

//+------+-----+-------------------------------------+
//|column|input|array_data                           |
//+------+-----+-------------------------------------+
//|bar   |foo  |{hello world, {Another String, {42}}}|
//+------+-----+-------------------------------------+
```

I guess this makes sense because a `List` is `::` (aka `$colon$colon`) of its head and tail, then  the tail is `::` of its head and tail etc.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the in-depth response.  I think I have a solution to my problem

Comment: Your observation pushed me in the right direction.  I previously tried returning a row, and that didn't work, but I think I wasn't setting the schema at that time.  I think the way to do this is: 1) return a row from the UDF and 2) set the schema when definiting the UDF.  These two things seem to work. I will answer my question in detail for posterity

Comment: I think I figure out how to use your reflection-based approach as well, but it's more complicated than the other approach.  In any event, you help is greatly appreciated!!! You're batting 1000!

Answer (score 1):

@Dmytro Mitin gets the majority of the credit for this answer.  Thanks a ton for your help!

The solution I came to uses approach 1) using the untyped APIs.  The key is to do two things:

1. Return a Row (e.g. untyped) from the unwrapped udf
2. Create the UDF using the untyped API

Here is the toy example

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF", "true")

def simpleFn(foo: Any): Row = Row("a_string", "hello world", 42L)

def simpleUdf = F.udf(
  simpleFn(_),
  dataType = T.StructType(
    List(
      T.StructField("a_string", T.StringType),
      T.StructField("another_string", T.StringType),
      T.StructField("an_int", T.LongType),
    )
  )
)
```

Now I can use it like this:

```
Seq(("bar", "foo"))
  .toDF("column", "input")
  .withColumn(
    "struct_data",
    simpleUdf($"input")
  )
  .withColumn(
    "field_data",
    $"struct_data.a_string"
  )
  .show(truncate=false)
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+---------------------------+----------+
|column|input|struct_data                |field_data|
+------+-----+---------------------------+----------+
|bar   |foo  |{a_string, hello world, 42}|a_string  |
+------+-----+---------------------------+----------+
```